# Sinch JS browser SDK working yet on IOS and Android?

Tags: sinch, android-sinch-api

We've been using Sinch JS SDK on OSX and Windows, but were told it doesn't work on IOS or Android. Now, there is the IOS native app SDK, so shouldn't there be support for the JS SDK as well?

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to that the web views dont have webrtc support (or well some android does, but its complicated)

Comment: We are using native browser not web views within a native app. Is there support yet for us?